# Passing reference types into variable argument list

Tags: c++

```
int g_myInt = 0;
int& getIntReference() { return g_myInt; }

void myVarArgFunction( int a, ... ) {
  // .........
}

int main() {
  myVarArgFunction( 0, getIntReference() );
  return 0;
}
```

In the (uncompiled and untested) C++ code above, is it valid to pass in an `int&` into a variable argument list? Or is it only safe to pass-by-value?

Comment: You can try it out on something like codepad...paste link: http://codepad.org/wFaWQrSE

Comment: why haven't you compiled and tested it?

Comment: @VaughnCato That's not a reliable way to learn standard behavior. It may work on MSVC and not on other platforms.

Comment: Agreed, but I think it would be a good first step.

Comment: FYI: g++ 4.6.3 doesn't complain.

Comment: @VaughnCato It's a moot attempt, honestly. It works just fine on MSVC from what I can tell but just want to make sure there is no tricky "undefined behavior" aspects to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 5.2.2.7 of the C++03 standard says that lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is first performed, so your function should receive a copy of the int instead of a reference.

I tried it with this program using g++ 4.6.3:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>

int g_myInt = 7;
int& getIntReference() { return g_myInt; }

void myVarArgFunction( int a, ... )
{
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap,a);
  int value = va_arg(ap,int);
  va_end(ap);
  std::cerr << value << "\n";
}

int main(int,char **)
{
  myVarArgFunction( 0, getIntReference() );
  return 0;
}
```

And got an output of 7.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not valid to pass in a reference because it is a non-POD type.

From the spec:

> If the argument has a non-POD class type, the behavior is undeﬁned.

See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983270/using-a-function-with-variable-argument-strings) on passing std::string, which is non-POD.
Code for reference: http://codepad.org/v7cVm4ZW

Comment: The expression `getIntReference()` has type `int` which is a POD type.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can pass a reference to an int as here.  You will be changing the global variable g_myInt if you changed that parameter in the function myVarArffunction...

Comment: l think you've got a different language in mind. (Or you're confusing references with pointers.) The va_ stuff doesn't do references, so they're converted to rvalues.