# c++ variable argument list

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I'm searching for answers but i can't find any relevant information on this. Let's take the example:

```
class MyClass
{
    //member functions and variables
};

void foo(int pivot,...)
{
    va_list arguments;  
    va_start(arguments,pivot);

    //va_arg(arguments,???)

    va_end(arguments);
}

void bar()
{
    MyClass a;
    MyClass * b = &a;
    const MyClass & c = a;
    foo(0,a,b,c);
}
```

How are the arguments `a`,`b` and `c` passed? By value , or by reference and how to ask for them using va_arg? What about the constructors/destructor for MyClass? Where in the c++ standard is this kind of behavior specified?

Comment: examples for `va_arg`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg

Comment: variadic functions: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic and variadic templates from c++11: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/EhvU7k9E/

Comment: You can't pass objects with user-defined constructors.

Comment: As for references, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/12613843/951890

Comment: @VaughnCato i'm trying to find this ban in standard... And cannot... Can you tell me paragraph where it's described?

Comment: @ForEveR: Actually it is just undefined behavior.  C++03 5.2.2.7.  However, g++ will give an error for it.

Comment: @ForEveR: Well, it will give an error if you have a user-defined copy constructor.

Comment: @VaughnCato IIRC, g++ will give a runtime error, not a compile time one.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I get `cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘struct A’ through '...'` with g++ 4.7.2.

Comment: @VaughnCato I've only tried it (accidentally) with older versions, and using `-std=c++98`.  In pre-C++11, it was undefined behavior; in C++11, it's "conditionally supported", which means a diagnostic if it isn't supported.  (Traditionally, it was held that a compiler could only refuse to compile a program with undefined behavior if it could prove that the code would actually be executed.  But a warning would have been nice; g++ inserted an illegal instruction where the copy constructor would have been called.)

Comment: instead of the C style "..." variable argument list, for C++ try call chaining, as the iostreams do. also consider variadic templates. both are type safe general ways to achieve the effect of a variable number of arguments, while "..." is not type safe and is not general, since it only supports POD types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never use user-defined types in var-arg function. Use C++11 variadic templates.

If your class is not pod-type - it's unspecified by standard, thanks to Vaughn Cato for remark

n3337 5.2.2/7

> Passing a potentially-evaluated argument of class type (Clause 9) having a nontrivial
> copy constructor, a non-trivial move constructor, or a non-trivial destructor, with no corresponding
> parameter, is conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics.

Else, you can and it will be correct, but you shouln't.

Comment: Then it should be safe just to use MyClass* only if really needed. I tested this msvc and it seems to be legit.

Comment: And of course, he doesn't show enough for us to conclude that `MyClass` is not a POD. Although traditionally, POD classes are defined with the `struct` keyword, something like `class MyClass { public : int a; int b; };` is perfectly legal, and is a POD.

Answer (score 3):

By value.  But beware, if `MyClass` is not a POD, the program
has undefined behavior (C++03, §5.2.2/7), or if `MyClass` has
a non-trivial copy constructor, move constructor or destructor,
the operation is conditionally supported, with implementation
defined semantics (C++11, §5.2.2/7).

In your example, passing `a` and passing `c` are exactly
identical operations (except that `c` cannot be bound to 
a non-const reference, but that's not an issue here, since
varargs are all pass by value).   Thus, when calling `foo`, you
pass `0`, a copy of `a`, a copy of the pointer `b`, and a copy
of `a`.  In order to access them in `foo`, you need to declare
the types in `va_arg` as `int`, `MyClass`, `MyClass*` and
`MyClass`.